# How can i set multiple colors to same log level in log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to have different colors to the same log level in log4j? For example, logger.debug() can configure with different colors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. With certain functions you can customize your log format and layout. More info here https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I checked given link. In Pattern Layout we can give different styles to log levels. what I am trying to do is create different Pattern Layouts for Log level debug for colors green and blue. In java depending upon message pass "appender-ref" so that same log level I can have different colors. For example logger.debugg("Message", Pattern) I am not sure if it is possible so checking on forum.

Comment: Ah, now i understand what you want. Not sure if you can do that, but you can define multiple loggers for different packages and let them have different layouts.